# Question about The Shallow Grave (Spell Card)

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Here is the chain of events: I activate [The Shallow Grave](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/The_Shallow_Grave) to special summon a needle worm from my graveyard (and my opponent chooses their monster), and then my opponent uses [D.D. Crow](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/D.D._Crow) to remove the needle worm from play.

Does my opponent still get the monster he has chosen to special summon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on this ruling on [Disappear](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Disappear):

> When a card that selects a card in the Graveyard as a target, such as "Monster Reborn", "Mask of Darkness", "Magician of Faith", "Spear Cretin", or "The Shallow Grave", is activated, you may chain "Disappear" to remove the targeted card from play, and the "Monster Reborn", etc., will **resolve without effect**. This is because these cards select their target at activation, not resolution.

[(Source)](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Card_Rulings%3aDisappear)

Your opponent wouldn't get the monster.

D.D. Crow appears to work exactly like Disappear when discarded.  So the same ruling should apply.

Comment: Aha, that is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for.